# Simular Hover con JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo un `navbar` de Bootstrap con desplegables. Quiero que al hacer `hover` en el desplegable `div class="dropdown-content"` se active también el `hover` de la opción del menú `a class="nav-link"`, ya que le tengo puesto estilos a la opción para `hover`, pero al moverme al desplegarse deja de ser `hover` sobre la opción y le quita el estilo.

El fragmento de html es el siguiente

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-database"><span class="tag">    BBDD<hr class="subrayado"></hr></span></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">    Clientes Totales</span></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">    Consulting</span></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">    Compliance</span></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">    Digital Transformation</span></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">    Tech Talent</span></i></a>
        </div>
</li>
```

y lo que estoy intentado con jQuery es lo siguiente:

```
$(".dropdown-content").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().children().find("a").trigger("mouseenter");
    }, function(){
    $(this).parent().children().find("a").trigger("mouseleave");
});
```

Cada vez que hago `hover` sobre el desplegable o salgo del desplegable me sale un error por consola que dice:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

A ver si me podéis ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Un Stack Overflow en toda regla ;)   Llamas al evento desde el propio evento, lo cual genera una acción cíclica .

Comment: pero estoy llamando al evento de otro elemento, ¿o me equivoco?

Comment: Pero se debe estar propagando, lo supongo por el error que lanza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y con sólo CSS?

El `:hover` en el `parent` (`.dropdown`) y filtrar los `children` del `dropdown-content` para sólo cambiar el que tiene el `:hover` propagado ( `.dropdown-content a:hover` ), así un sólo evento cambia varias cosas.

```css
.dropdown {
  background: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.dropdown>.nav-link {
  background: yellow;
}

.dropdown:hover>.nav-link {
  background: red;
}


/*****/

.navbar-nav {}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.nav-item.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  width: 10rem;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">asdfasdf</li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-database"><span class="tag">BBDD<hr class="subrayado" /></span></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">Clientes Totales</span></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">Consulting</span></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">Compliance</span></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">Digital Transformation</span></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"><span class="tag">Tech Talent</span></i></a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
<script>
    $(".dropdown-content").hover(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().children().find("a").trigger("mouseenter");

    }, function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().children().find("a").trigger("mouseleave");        
    });
</script>
```

Fuente: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Si evitamos la propagación del evento quizá detengamos el que colapsa la pila.

Otra opción sería jugar con las clases:

```
<script>
    $(".dropdown-content").hover(function (event) {
        $(this).parent().children().find("a").addClass("simula-mouseenter");

    }, function (event) {
        $(this).parent().children().find("a").removeClass("simula-mouseenter");        
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto; activará el hover a nav-link:

```
var link=window.location;
if(link=='http://www.tu-sitio-donde-quieres-el-hover'){
 $('li.nav-item .nav-link').addClass('hover');
}
```